# Convert string array to JSON object/Array

Tags: javascript, json

How can convert this JavaScript string array to a JSON strin:

```
var arr = "{'id': '10', 'name': 'test1'},{'id': '11', 'name': 'test2'}";
```

so that can access the members like `arr[0].id`, `arr[0].name`, etc?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. Your example string is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there isn't quite valid `JSON`.  It needs to be surrounded with `[]` and use `"` instead of `'`:

```
var arr = '[{"id": "10", "name": "test1"},{"id": "11", "name": "test2"}]';
```

To parse it, you can use

```
var parsedArray = JSON.parse(arr);
```

and then access using

```
parsedArray[0].id
```

Note that this is assuming the `JSON` is stored as a string to begin with and you are getting it from somewhere in that format. If you are actually just trying to create an array and access its elements, you should use an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals) as @bfavaretto answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really defining that string directly in code, just use an array literal instead:

```
var arr = [
    {'id': 10, 'name': 'test1'},
    {'id': 11, 'name': 'test2'}
];

console.log(arr[0].id); // 10
```

<sup>If it's not that, please edit more information into your question, like where is the string coming from, and what does it look like *exactly*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery just use:

```
jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );
```

It's exactly what you're looking for

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: why -1? please explain

Comment: (a) The `javascript` tag says *Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.* **however** (b) There is no jQuery in your answer, your mention of it is a red herring, **however** (c) You can't parse that string with `JSON.parse` as it is not valid JSON **but** you edited your answer so it *does* include jQuery so *a* now applies.

Comment: @aaronman — No, because it is wrong answer that doesn't work.

Comment: @Quentin I think it's more important to DV the question, as he states he is trying to parse a JSON array but does not give one which is misleading and confusing to someone answering the question

Comment: @aaronman — No, he says is is trying to convert "a JavaScript string array" **to** a JSON array.

Comment: @Quentin "a JavaScript string array" is not a real thing, maybe the answer should really be more of tutorial than this simple solution

Comment: @aaronman — It might not be a technical term, but since he provided example input, it is pretty clear what it means.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33797/discussion-between-aaronman-and-quentin)

Comment: i tried this in jQuery but not working...                                                 var arr = "{'id': '10', 'name': 'test1'},{'id': '11', 'name':'test2'}"       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(arr);
alert( obj);                                                                         but obj is not showing anything in alert

Comment: @NasirZaman — No, it wouldn't do. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you don't have JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly confusing.
Javascript objects in serialized, string form are in JSON.
Your string looks like it wants to be JSON. If it were JSON, you could JSON.parse() it into an object.
If you have a Javascript object, you can JSON.stringify() it into a string.
You may need the json2.js library, depending on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a data-interchange format primarily intended for transmission of data between systems.  Nonetheless, I interpreted your question as follows:

1. Create an array of objects
2. Access properties of these objects

If this is the case, then @bfavaretto is correct in that what you really want is an array literal whose elements are objects.  You can then access each individual object by index and any properties of that object by specifying the property name.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below code

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[' + arr+ ']');
```

where as jsonObj you can use it as a JSON object

Comment: No. `$` is undefined and JSON requires that strings are delimited with `"` characters, not `'` characters.

Comment: thanks for your information. but i thought that will work